# Is there a way to print a certain part of the summary of a model?

Tags: r

I wish to print a part of my summary when reviewing my model (more to save space and for a clearer output), if there anyway to do this? All want is the variance table as circled below

[image]

model used;

```
pupils_test_model = lmer(IQ ~ ses + (1 | Class), 
                    data = pupils)
```

Comment: Could you please include the code showing how you generated the model.

Comment: @G5W Sure, I'll add the model to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to get those lines,  you could just use `capture.output` and then select the relevant lines.

```
temp = capture.output(summary(model))
Start = grep("Random effects", temp)
End   = grep("Number of obs", temp)
print(unname(temp[Start:End]))

[1] "Random effects:"                                  
[2] " Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr "
[3] " Petal.Length (Intercept) 2.16667  1.4720        "
[4] "              Petal.Width 0.62156  0.7884   -0.91"
[5] " Residual                 0.08241  0.2871        "
[6] "Number of obs: 150, groups:  Petal.Length, 43"
```

Comment: Great! In a beamer slideshow produced with knitr I used `cat(paste(temp[Start:End], collapse= "\n"))` which perfectly fitted my needs. I could display a lmer output on two slides.